# Django seems to import packages from global installations rather then from my Virtual Environment(venv)

Tags: python, django, pandas, virtualenv

I have created a Virtual Environment using Python's built-in venv. Activated the environment & installed the necessary packages. But cannot import Pandas in the Django project.
Later I figured out that Django might be importing packages from the global packages installed before, where pandas was not installed. Do I have to change anything in my Django project settings or in my Virtual Environment?

1. Activated Virtual Environment(venv)
   [image: Image of the activated venv]
2. This is when I try to import Pandas
   [image: trying to import pandas]

Comment: Click on the python interpreter in vscode (bottom left) and select the one from the venv.

Comment: Is your problem with vscode or are you unable to load pandas after running the application?

Comment: How exactly are you starting your Django server?

Comment: Hello @DiptangsuGoswami, thank you so much for responding. I was running the developer server using 'python3 manage.py runserver' command.
Pandas was loading fine in the terminal but wasn't in VSCode.

Comment: @DiptangsuGoswami Now I have followed your instruction and changed the environment from the bottom left corner. Now it's working fine. Can't thank you enough. I have been stuck here for the last 4 hours trying to figure out the problem. Thanks a million brother.

Answer (score 0):

Select your environment in vscode by clicking on

> Python 3.8.5 64 bit

located on bottom left corner. A window will come up on the top, your virtual environment will be available in the list select it.